# How do i get a href value from a link within a ul li list

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list such as:

```
<ul id="cities">
  <li><a href="/london/">London<a></li>
  <li><a href="/new-york/">New York<a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris/">Paris<a></li>
<ul>
```

using jquery how do i get the href value for "New York"?  Only the anchor text value is known through the client so i would like to find the matching anchor text and extract the href.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$("#cities li a:contains(New York)").attr('href');
```

Or more longer, but more accurate (since `:contains()` would match "New York City" as well), you can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for an *exact* match, like this:

```
$("#cities li a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "New York";
}).attr('href');
```

Comment: @Akk - Are you running it on `document.ready`, wrapped inside a `$(function() { });` for example?  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yadpJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
var href = $('ul#cities li a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "New York";
}).attr('href');
```

Comment: @James - That's *usually* true, but not 100% of the time, one script may be used on a dozen pages, what if `#cities` was a div listing cities, completely unrelated on another page?  It *can* matter is the point :)  Don't get me wrong though, if you're 100% certain of the ID usage then by all means leave it off, it is a faster selector.

Comment: @James yes, as Nick says it's something I do as a sanity check, and I do it in examples here because it helps clarify. One never knows how accurate are the snippets of sample code in questions here!

Comment: ul#cities is slower than #cities, since #cities will use the native document.getElementById() method.

Comment: @David - So will `ui#cities` :) It just does an additional check afterwards, you can see the sizzle source here: http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js

Comment: @David I was under the (mis)impression that Sizzle would check the node *after* fetching by "id" value, but looking at the (dense) code I think you're probably right. When it "chunks" the selector it subsequently only treats pieces that *start* with "#" as "ID" selectors. Good to know!  Thanks. (edit - ok Nick I'll look it over again; that code is worth studying as an exercise in any case!)

Comment: Wow. This generated some comments :D. I meant to say from a performance point of view (and if there is no other reason such as multiple ids)